# Why pg_largeobject is growing?

Tags: postgresql, wso2, blob, wso2-streaming-integrator

I've got a system (WSO2SP) which uses PostgreSQL. It stores BLOBs and uses `pg_largeobject`. I don't have control over how the system uses this Postgres feature. The issue is that the table `pg_largeobject` is growing constantly and the only way to keep it from growing is cleaning the table using a scheduled task.

Is it possible to analyze requests, queries or another activity to understand why the table might be growing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Mohandarshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2168723/mohanadarshan) on [Siddhi Slack](https://siddhi-io.slack.com/archives/CMFB1PUCW/p1578036676086900?thread_ts=1577697390.071700&cid=CMFB1PUCW)

As per the default behaviour, state persistence revisions are get cleaned automatically in Siddhi.

In Postgres, there is a separate table to handle the [large object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/catalog-pg-largeobject.html).
This is not cleaned even the actual data is removed. In our case, even state persistence data is removed respective pg_largeobject entry is not getting deleted.

It seems, Postgres recommends to remove them using the DB trigger or manual process. You can refer to the [guide](https://tutel.me/c/dba/questions/112637/can+i+do+vacuum+full+to+pg_largeobject+table) to get some understanding. Please get help from Postgres community, if you need further guidance on this.